# meaning of Scala operator "<=>"

Tags: scala

I am very new to Scala and I have to solve a null error case. I have been suggested to use `<=>` to solve it. I google it no materials or reference related to it. Can anyone help me to understand what is the meaning of `<=>` and how to use it. Any documentation of this would be very helpful but Google not able to find it.

Specifically, what is the meaning of the below statement.

```
val filteredDF = df.filter(df("column") <=> (new Column(Literal(null))))
```

Comment: There isn't such an operator in scala, this is just a valid identifier, which could be the name of a method or a class or object such as "foo", so we cannot know what <=> means without seeing where it is defined. It doesn't have any special meaning in scala

Comment: Thanks Stew. val filteredDF = df.filter(df("column") <=> (new Column(Literal(null))))       Can you explain me how to interpret "<=>" keyword here ?

Comment: its not a keyword. That is calling a method named `<=>` on the result of `df("column")` and passing `new Column(Literal(null))` as the argument to this method

Comment: I am close to understand this, thanks stew... you mean... <==> is the method name???

Comment: yes, somewhere, someone wrote a method: `def <=>(c: Column): sometype = …`

Comment: The first place to look is in the class for whatever type is returned by `df("column")`

Comment: Great stew. Got it. Thanks so much for your time. You have saved my time.